# Integration of a continuous function on a closed interval

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Let $f: \ [a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Since it is continuous, it is Riemann-integrable.

Let $F: \ [a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $ F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt $. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, on the **open** interval $(a, b), $ $ F'(x)=f(x) $ (i.e. $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$).

Suppose that we want to calculate the integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$, i.e. the value of $F(b)$. In practice we do that by finding any antiderivative of $f$ and by computing its values at $x=a$ and $x=b$. But, if we are being pedantic, we can't really do that because the fundamental theorem says that $F'(x)=f(x)$ only on the open interval! $F$ is defined on a closed interval so it is not differentiable at points $x=a$ and $x=b$ (at least not by the common definition of derivative). The fundamental theorem does not say anything about the values of $F$ at the boundary points.

So how could this 'formal error' be fixed? How can we define the values of $F$ at $x=a$ and $x=b$ **rigorously**?

One way I could think of doing this is that we define $F(a)=0$. This is intuitive but could it also be according to some axiom of integrals? Then I would also want to define $F(b)=\lim_{x \rightarrow b-} F(x)$ but I'm not sure how to justify it and how to guarantee that the limit exists.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that $F'(x)=f(x)$ only on $(a,b)$? That equality also holds when $x=a$ or $x=b$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos For example, on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part

Comment: Right. That's strange, but take a look [here](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/5-3-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus).

Comment: Formally, you can’t speak of the derivative of $F$ at $b$ as $F$ is not defined on a neighborhood of $b$. However, the left derivative of $F$ at $b$ is well defined.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you -- however I don't see there any justifications to this 'problem'. In the proof of the fundamental theorem, $F'(x)$ is calculated according to the definition. If you substituted $x=b$, you would have to be able to integrate $f$ around the boundary point but $f$ is not defined for $x>b$.

Comment: So, you claim that, say, the null function on $[0,1]$ is neither differentiable at $0$ nor at $1$, right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, that's the definition which I prefer to use. On the Wikipedia page 'derivative' it's defined as follows: A function $f$ of a real variable is differentiable at a point $a$ of its domain, if its domain contains an **open** interval **containing** $a$, and the limit $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists.

Comment: I see. So, as far as you are concerned, the statement “If $I$ is an interval of $\Bbb R$ with more than one point and if $f$ is a function form $I$ into $\Bbb R$, then $f$ is constant if and only if $(\forall x\in I):f'(x)=0$” is false, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It's starting to get embarrassing to continuously cite Wikipedia, but on the page 'Constant function' it is said: If $y'(x)=0$ **for all real numbers** $x$, then $y$ is a constant function. According to that definition your example function is not a constant function unless $I=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's just plain wrong. What you quote says that **if** $y'(x)=0$ for every real number $x$, **then** $y$ is constant. It does **not** say that those are the only constant functions. But if you want to use Wikipedia as a reference, that's fine by me. See what it says about [constant functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function): “a constant function is a function whose (output) value is the same for every input value”. Now, please answer me with a simple “yes” or “no”: as far as you are concerned, the null function from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb R$ is constant or not?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay yes, I consider that function to be constant. And right, that statement of yours (characterization of constant functions) does not make sense when using the (in my opinion) common Wikipedia definition of derivative since it does not define derivative at boundary points. But I hope that this is really leading to something.

Comment: Yes. It leads for you to spend the next yours of your life writing to Calculus textbooks authors telling them that they are wrong. Such as Michael Spivak who wrote, in is *Calculus* that “If $f$ is a constant function, $f(x)=c$, then $f'(a)=0$ for all numbers $a$.” That's theorem 1, from chapter 10. Have fun.

Comment: Surely it depends. Is $f$ continuous and exists only on $(a,b)$ or $\forall x$